# Time complexity of Bayesian Ridge Regression

Tags: regression, bayesian, ridge-regression, time-complexity

What is the training and inference time complexity of Bayesian Ridge Regression (e.g. [as implemented in sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.BayesianRidge.html)) in terms of the number of samples *n* and the number of features *d*?